# Cant fix directory in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, directory

I tried to do install yandex browser. Something went wrong and now i get this message:

```
N: Ignoring file 'yandex-browser.list.save.1' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'yandex-browser.list.save.2' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Type 'andex.ru/yandex-browser/deb' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yandex-browser.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
N: Ignoring file 'yandex-browser.list.save.1' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'yandex-browser.list.save.2' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Type 'andex.ru/yandex-browser/deb' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yandex-browser.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Can somebody help me? Im new to linux.When i tried to remove file from directory,it said i dont have permission to do that,i think. Thanks

Comment: Well, i dont know why i got downvoted. I really need your help. im very new to linux and now i cant even update the system because of this problem. I would appreciate your help. I dont know if im asking the right question. PLEASE HELP!

Answer (score 0):

I made another question about the same error and @pilot6 answered this:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yandex-browser*
```

This fixed the problem.